# how can override + operator for HashSet<T> in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, hashset

we can override any operations (for ex: '+') for the existing class?
I want override + operation for merge 2 HashSet and removing duplicate values.

In this case, I want override + operation for HashSet, but I have no idea how to implement + operator for an existing class.
All tutorials on the internet implemented operators for a new class. Given the generic type of SetHash, how can I perform + operation?

I Created a class to implement + Operator:

```
    public static HashSet<T> operator +(HashSet<T> left, HashSet<T> right)  where T : class
    {
        return left.Union(right);
    }
```

But not work and give many errors (23 errors). Some of them are:

> .operator +(HashSet, HashSet)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

I think I can solve this problem with an extension method, But I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overloading explicitly only applies to user defined types. It is actually the [1st sentence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading). However you can create a class that Inherits from `HastSet<T>` - it is not sealed, after all. With the sole purpose of adding that function/override.

```
public class AddAbleHashSet<T> : HashSet<T> {
    public static HashSet<T> operator +(HashSet<T> left, HashSet<T> right)  where T : class
    {
        return left.Union(right);
    } 
}
```

P.S.: I am unsure what the `where T : class` restriction on the function is doing. You are Merging two hashsets. The type T does not mater at all for this. I am actually unsure if that is even valid there.

Comment: you're right; I must remove `where T : class`, but give me an error _one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type_

Comment: The implementation should actually be `left.UnionWith(right); return left;` of course. (HashSet<T> does not contain a method called "Union()" - rather, it contains one called "UnionWith()` which does not return anything.)

Comment: I founded  solution [At least one parameter type of this binary operator must be the containing type '<typename>'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc33021)

Comment: I would create and return a new HashSet, because you don't expect an input operand to be changed.